# Surreal early anime movie?

Tags: story-identification

Probably some time in the '90s, I came home late at night and there was an anime feature film on TV. I watched it for quite a while, although I remember very little.

In the scene I remember, a group of characters on a journey encounter an isolated lake. The main character, a girl, disrobes, and goes for a dip in the lake. I seem to recall a visual emphasis on the glisten of light on the water, and a peaceful feel to the moment.

The characters may have been fleeing a threat in a city, or on a quest for something or other.  There was a group of them.  I think the movie had a surreal quality to it.

I've looked at lots of early anime titles, but no luck yet.  Any idea what movie this is?

Comment: Is there a sci-fi element in this anime? Either way, you might want to add [some detail](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to your question.

Comment: There's a wikia page for [skinny dipping in anime](http://animebaths.wikia.com/wiki/Skinny_Dipping/Scenes); take a look there and post here if you find the film you're looking for.

Comment: What does early anime mean?

Comment: +1 to what does "early anime" mean?  IIRC, the first proper TV/movie format anime started in the 50s or so.  Was this a really old (ie: maybe 50s - 70s) anime that you were watching in the 90s, or was it a 90s anime?

Comment: The first thing that come to my mind (a girl, disrobes, and goes for a dip in the lake) is the "Taarna" segment from the movie "Heavy Metal". But she was alone not with a group.

Comment: When you say "anime" do you mean specifically Japanese-style animation or just animated in general? It makes a big difference to those who are into animation in a big way.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, folks.  I am regrettably ignorant about anime.  But I believe it was Japanese, with English subtitles.  Sorry for the lack of data, it's an old memory.  I believe the girl had long, dark hair.  The lake was first viewed from a distance, and I recall that she walked into the water from a sloping shore, like a beach.    I strongly believe there were fantasy and/or scifi elements to the movie, but I'm unclear about the bulk of the content.  If I had to guess I'd say it might be 70s.  I think there might have been children in the group of travelers.

Comment: probably 0rion didn't mean [granadier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSIjcZJdCkM), but it comes very close. now... why is [this other very similar question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175415/what-anime-is-this-image-from?newreg=84f27b09d3564a82b87d15e40aa28a12) not considered out of scope as well? do you happen to know why, @valorum? i would understand a question about azumanga daioh could be considered out of scope, but just mentioning "anime" is almost sure it will be about either sci fi or fantasy... isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, cregox.  I looked at that scene, but I don't think that's it-- plus I really think it was a full-length movie.  But you're right; that scene is a lot like what I'm describing.  Sorry I don't have more info, I sense there are a lot of brains here ready to fire into action.