# What anime is this image from?

Tags: story-identification, anime

[image: this]

I found this image on some random Facebook comment, but it looks so good... just trying to find what's the source

Comment: could be one piece(character name katakuri)

Comment: [I am told](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43628/which-anime-is-this?noredirect=1#comment58484_43628) that this would be a suitable question here, so I have migrated it.

Comment: @senshin - Suitable and answerable :-)

Comment: why is this suitable and [that](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151693/surreal-early-anime-movie) isn't?

Answer (score 13):

Google reverse image search [tells me](https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FYhfAw.jpg) that this is

> "one piece charlotte katakuri".

Indeed, this is [fanart of the character "Charlotte Katakuri"](https://merimo-animation.deviantart.com/art/Charlotte-Katakuri-One-Piece-674463607) from *[One Piece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Piece)*, by a user on DeviantArt named "merimo-animation". There is a watermark on the original image that would also point you in this direction, but of course it's been cropped out because people are butts about crediting content-creators.

[image]